# How do i kill a CMD process?

Tags: vb.net, exit, kill

This is a simple code line i've made for my application. Basically `Button_2` runs the "batchfile.bat." Now, i'm curious how to make `Button_1` end the "batchfile.bat" or close CMD because thats what the "batchfile.bat" makes run. Any helps appreciated, thanks.

```
Public Class Form1 
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
        Handles Button2.Click 
        Process.Start("C:\batchfile.bat") 
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Handles Button1.Click
        (MY DESIRED CODE TO KILL CMD HERE) 
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You probably got downvoted due to a lack of language you're working with. I know it's VB but not sure if it's VBA, VB6 or VB.NET.

Comment: @Tyriar `Process.Start()` indicates it's VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_methods%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). You're probably looking for the [`Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method.